# Retrieve FeatureMember Tags from geoserver that have certain value in one attribute

Tags: geoserver

If I send this request to my geoserver (2.4.4):

http://mygeoserver.de?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mytype:mylayer&maxFeatures=50

I get an xml document like this:

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection ...>
<gml:featureMember>....
<mytype:INDEX>0</mytype:INDEX>
</gml:featureMember>
<gml:featureMember>....
<mytype:INDEX>1</mytype:KINDEX>
</gml:featureMember>
<gml:featureMember>....
<mytype:INDEX>0</mytype:KINDEX>
</gml:featureMember>
```

I want to query my geoserver that I retrieve only those featureMembers that have a certain value in the tag `mytype:INDEX`, for example all featureMembers with the INDEX `1`.

Can I do that and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [Filtering in GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/index.html) to accomplish this.

The simplest way to do this from your perspective would be to use a [cql filter](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html) on the end of your request.

e.g.
http://mygeoserver.de?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mytype:mylayer&maxFeatures=50&cql_filter=INDEX=1